# Static template tag for Django template engine

Tags: django

I have the following code:

```
<img src="{% static 'images/{{i.sideid.sidepic}}' %}"/>
```

But this doesn't load the picture...

However, if I change the `{{i.sideid.sidepic}}` to the picture name "republic.png" it works tho. So, yeah, `{{i.sideid.sidepic}}` is actually the exact same name ("republic.png"), because I do a print in django views and shows it in my cmd, the exact same name "republic.png".

I guess there has to be a specific way to add that {{i.sideid.sidepic}} inside the jinja {% %} .

Comment: None of this is Jinja at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to concatenate strings with the [`add` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add):

```
{% with 'images/'|add:i.sideid.sidepic as image %}
  {% static image %}
{% endwith %}
```

N.B. The variable directly following the `as` can be anything you want:

```
{% with 'images/'|add:i.sideid.sidepic as sidepic %}
  {% static sidepic %}
{% endwith %}
```

What you are trying to do doesn't quite work with the `static` template tag because it takes either a string or a variable.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @micheal j roberts , thanks for the quick response but it is not working :( . Also, my folder is called imatges :P

Comment: @ArnauEspin Hi - try it now. If you receive an error, could you add the stack trace to your question please and what you attempted. :)

Comment: I wanna point out that I changed the folder name by myself hehe, but thanks!

Comment: {% with 'imatges/'|add:i.sideid.sidepic as image %}
                    <img src="{% static image %}"/>
                    
                    {% endwith %}

Comment: @Hi Arnau - awesome, yes I revised my answer when you said it was `imatges` - I assumed in my original answer that the was a typo! :) Try it now as in, try my new answer. Hopefully this is acceptable for checking off as the answer! :)

Comment: Yes, I didnt mention it was a django templates, apologies!

Comment: @ArnauEspin No worries, the Django templating engine came out from Jinja - and there are many similarities. The Django templating engine has built upon some core templating variables/hooks. So, minor differences - I knew tho as soon as I saw `{% static %}` what you meant. :)

Comment: @Selcuk It's good that you raised it - I think Arnau may now take a look at the differences between the two engines. :)